# How to plot a ROC curve using dataframe converted from CSV file

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I was trying to plot a ROC curve by using the documentation provided by sklearn. My data is in a CSV file, and it looks like this.It has two classes 'Good'and 'Bad'

screenshot of my CSV file

[image: screenshot of my CSV file]

And my code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle
import sys
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from scipy import interp
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# Import some data to play with
df = pd.read_csv("E:\\autodesk\\TTI ROC curve.csv")
X =df[['TTI','Max TemperatureF','Mean TemperatureF','Min TemperatureF',' Min Humidity']].values
y = df['TTI_Category'].as_matrix()
# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=['Good','Bad'])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

# shuffle and split training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5,
                                                    random_state=0)

# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                                 random_state=random_state))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()enter code here
```

If i run this code the system told me random_state is not defined. so I changed it to random_state=true. Then the system told me

```
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange', KeyError: 2 <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xd8bff60>
```

if I print out n_classes. The system told me it's "1", and if I print out the n_classes in the documentation it says 3. I'm not sure if that's where the problem is. Does anyone have answer to this traceback?

Comment: You should provide some information about what errors does the code raise. 
Also, don't expect people to guide you "line by line" though documentation.

Comment: Thanks Danlele. If i run this code the system told me  random_state is not defined. so I changed it to random_state=true. Then the system told me  
 "plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange',

KeyError: 2

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xd8bff60>". Does anyone have answer to this traceback?

Comment: oh by the way if I print out n_classes. The system told me it's "1". I'm not sure if that's where the problem is.

Comment: pls do not use the comments space for such kind of clarifications & addditional info - edit & update your post instead!

Comment: Thanks Desertnaut. I'm new to stack overflow. Thank you for letting me know about the format issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you simply don't understand how your data is structured and how your code should work.

`LabelBinarizer` will return a one-v-all encoding, meaning that for two classes you will get the following mapping: `['good', 'bad', 'good'] -> [[1], [0], [1]]`, s.t. `n_classes = 1`.

Why would you expect it to be 3 if you have 2 classes? 
Simply change `plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange', lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])` to `plt.plot(fpr[0], tpr[0], color='darkorange', lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[0])` and you should be good.

Comment: Dear Mr Daniele:  Thanks a lot for your patience and help. May I please bother you one more time. As you mentioned in your answer, since I only have two classes; therefore, n_classes =1. Then what about if I have three classes lets say: y= label_binarize([1, 6], classes=[0,1,2]). I tried this myself and got n_classes =3. So does that mean that n_classes will never equal to 2? If yes, then why is that. Thanks a lot Mr Daniele for your help.

Comment: And another question Mr Daniele. why changing     fpr[2], tpr[2],roc_auc[2] to fpr[0], tpr[0],roc_auc[0] made the whole thing work. I tried to change everything to 1 since n_classes=1 (since python starts from 0 therefore I thought n_classes =1 means both 0 and 1 should be OK) and the system gave me a keyerror:1. Finally Mr Daniele, since I have two classes, then can I plot a ROC curve for each classes or I can only do that if I have more than two classes. Thanks again for your time and patience. I hope you all the best.

Comment: Sorry Mr Daniele again for the formatting. I was trying to change all the code in my comment to correct format, but I failed to do so within five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just look in `tpr` and `fpr` dictionaries and you will see that you don't have a `tpr[2]` or `fpr[2]`. `n_classes = y.shape[1]` shows how many classes you have (= 2), which means that you have keys of `0` and `1` in your `tpr` and `fpr` dictionaries.

You are overcomplicating things by using a multi-class approach when you only have 2 classes (binary classification). I think you are using [this tutorial.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)

I would advise replacing the following:

```
# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])
```

With something like:

```
fpr, tpr = roc_curve(y_test.values, y_score[:,1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr,tpr)
plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
```

Comment: Dear Stev. If you please can you kindly have a look at my updated question. I have tried your advice and got some traceback. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Try using `fpr, tpr = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)`.